# Dynamic function with type hinting

Tags: dynamic, clojure, metadata, eval

I'm trying to generate functions in runtime with hinted parameters.

The parameters symbols are know during runtime.

If I knew them in advance I could create function dynamically like this:

```
(def foo 
  (eval 
    (list 'fn '[^String a] (list '.length 'a))))
```

which has desired performance:

```
user=> (time (reduce + (map foo (repeat 1000000 "asdf")  )))
"Elapsed time: 164.578 msecs"
4000000
```

as opposed to:

```
(def bar
  (eval 
    (list 'fn '[a] (list '.length 'a))))

user=> (time (reduce + (map bar (repeat 1000000 "asdf")  )))
"Elapsed time: 2392.271 msecs"
4000000
```

Now. The problem I have is how to create such functions in runtime with dynamic list of arguments. E.g.:

```
(def baz
  (let [args '[a b]]    
    (eval
      (list 
        'fn 
        (vec (flatten (map (fn [ar] `[^String ~ar]) args))) 
        (list '.length (first args))))))
#'user/baz

user=> (time (reduce + (map baz (repeat 1000000 "asdf") (repeat 1000000 "asdf"))))
"Elapsed time: 2467.178 msecs"
4000000
```

It looks like syntax quote prevents compiler or reader macro from interpreting type hinting. 
How can I achieve dynamic function generation with type hints?

P.S. I know that such function creation looks crazy and that one may suggest use macros instead of eval, but I have sound reasons to do it this way.

P.P.S Is there any other way of creating lambda with parameters known in runtime other than with special form 'fn' and eval?

Comment: ^ is a reader macro, so the ^String is applied to ~ar and never seen by eval.

Comment: Don't understand your P.P.S. question or its motivation. Higher order functions (in this case functions which return functions) would be the preference in most cases. Perhaps you could expand on your thoughts in a new question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you insist:

```
(defn bazy [arglist]
  (let [args (mapv #(with-meta (symbol %) {:tag 'String}) arglist)]
    (eval (list 'fn args (list '.length (first arglist))))))

(def baz (bazy '[a b]))
```

Comment: Drat. Too slow with the keyboard.

Comment: P.S. Note that by not evaluating the arguments (via quoting) and evaluating the result, you are essentially doing the work of a macro here, just at runtime rather than (macro-)compile time.

Comment: Thank you very much A. Webb. That was exactly what I was looking for. The motivation is the library I'll opensource soon. It is automatic algorithmic differentiation tool. The code defining expresions to differentiate is not known at compile time as it will be defined via java dsl. There will be pure clojure usage as well which can user macros.